# Дефекты в редакторе brackets в ОС Ubuntu

Tags: html, linux, ubuntu, brackets, adobe-brackets

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде, если присмотреться, между символами дефекты в виде каких-то линий, точек и прочее. Может быть, кто-нибудь знает, в чем причина и как это можно исправить?

Лично я думаю, что дело в Ubuntu, т.к. при работе с этим редактором в Windows 10 этой проблемы не возникало.

Comment: в других редакторах проявляется такая же проблема (если выставить такой же шрифт и размер)?

Comment: Драйвер на видео какой?

Comment: В других редакторах проблем не наблюдается и драйвер стоит nvidia-driver-440. Пробовал в настройка менять драйвера на версию младше, на драйвер от Убунту - без результата.